# com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception:Android resource linking failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

Android resource linking failed
F:\New folder\BikhuApp\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\com\adhoc\ctnrbuzz\balaapp\R.java: error: invalid symbol name 'com.adhoc.ctnrbuzz.balaapp:id/null'.

com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
F:\New folder\BikhuApp\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\com\adhoc\ctnrbuzz\balaapp\R.java: error: invalid symbol name 'com.adhoc.ctnrbuzz.balaapp:id/null'.

```
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create(Aapt2Exception.kt:45)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create$default(Aapt2Exception.kt:39)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doLink(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:191)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:103)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:176)
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:858)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$AaptSplitInvoker.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:797)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$AaptSplitInvoker.run(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:669)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:262)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:47)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:273)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:49)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:134)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$3(CacheStep.java:83)
at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Clean the project. If this did not solve the issue. Try with Invalidecache and restart which is in the file option.

Comment: Did you set one of your IDs in your XML to null?

Comment: You defined an ID somewhere in your resources that's named `null`. For example, you might a have some `<View>` in one of your layouts with `android:id="@+id/null"`. You cannot use `null` as a resource name, since it has a special meaning in Java. Find where you have that `id`, change it to something else, then rebuild your project.

Answer (score -1):

Try from Android Studio Menu `File->Invalidate Caches/Restart->Invalidate and Restart`

Comment: If this were to solve the issue, then it is a non-reproducible problem, and should be closed as such, not answered. You can make this suggestion in a comment instead.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for replying . i have tried the above and its not working . pls help . Thanks in advance

Comment: @MikeM. sorry. What should I do now? I sometimes don't get why users replies to a question in comment instead an answer

Comment: No worries. It was merely advice for future reference. The OP has apparently tried this now, and it hasn't helped, which is to be expected, actually, since they got a rather specific error. You can just delete this, if you like. No harm, no foul. :-) Cheers!

Comment: "I sometimes don't get why users replies to a question in comment instead an answer" – It's a judgment call, really. If the problem is a simple typo, or an IDE glitch, for instance, it's best to just leave a comment to that effect, and flag to close the question, as appropriate.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for your kind reply. I'll keep those advices in mind

Comment: FWIW I had this issue and this suggestion solved it for me